# how to mask a domain in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php website. There is a domain example http://www.mydomain.com/clubs.php I want to mast it to http://www.mydomain.com/groups.php and the rest of the address will remain the same. Is it possible.

Please guide me how to achive it..

Comment: What do you mean by "mask"?

Comment: if anyone open the website club.php it should show in address bar as groups.php.

Comment: Like forwarding from clubs.php to groups.php?

Comment: yes correct like forwarding but it want it should show group.php in address bar it should not show clubs.php

Comment: Keyword: URL rewriting. Google it. This is not about "domains".

Answer (score 2):

You could create a new file named `groups.php` and include in it `clubs.php`.
Or you could use `mod_rewrite` via `.htaccess` file.

For including file use:

```
<?php include_once 'clubs.php'; ?>
```

For rewriting use and add it after line `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^groups.php$ clubs.php [L]
```

Hope I've understood what you're talking about with *mask*.

Comment: yes I have created a new file but if I open links present in clubs.php its not opening. I want it to be dont with .htaccess. Can you please guide me how to achive it.

Comment: Could you provide `clubs.php` content?

Comment: there is no other way unless you want to change all of your links. Either .htaccess or make some variable $link = "where_it_should_go.php" and assign it the values you need in the clubs.php

Comment: If you have a link like `<a href="clubs.php?foo=bar">` you can change it to: `<a href="?foo=bar">` so file name isn't set and works.

Comment: It's a little hard helping you without further info, could you at least provide a _non working link_ ?

Comment: Its working, I just want this club not to show in address bar. This only I want..

Comment: So read my answer, create a new file named `groups.php` and include `clubs.php`.

Comment: how to include it ? I copied all the text from club to group.. but its not working. All the links are refering to club. php

Comment: Excuse me, but are you reading answers and comments? We have said to you everything. Also, we asked you to show us your file for helping you and you said no...

Comment: Dear I am sorry. Actually I am new in this webstie so i dont know. I just found out your answers..

Comment: Please wait for 2 min I will put to code and come back to you... please wait.. thanks...

Comment: No problem mate, just asking :) Try to reload page and check out answers & comments :)

Comment: Yes I have done Its working only for first page. If I click anyother links its showing again clubs.php/asddsfah/asdfladj somthing like this..

Comment: can u guide me jan how to use modrewrite. I am using phpbb forum and I use a mod before for SEO for URL. I have .htaccess file in my ftp. But i dont know the code I have to place in htaccess file.

Comment: I have added again its doing the same thing. Its only working for first file another link its showing the same club on the address bar. can u please modify it..

Comment: We need to see `clubs.php`, and maybe also `groups.php`. Use http://pastebin.com and remove sensitive information!

Comment: this pastebin website is not loading........... any other or do i send u the mail..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PdUaBi1Q Here i have uploaded. can u check please and let me know if its open

Comment: Oh my god, that's a phpBB file. You can't do what you are trying

Comment: :) there is no way... its very very important to me... What I am thiking is it possible if I change all clubs to group in alllllllllllll the files ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then you need to use apache directive URLRewrite (mod_rewrite). Google it. It's complex to explain here, but basicaly there are few lines to add in .htaccess file and your webserver must support it. Some do not supoprt for securty reasons. If the server is administered by you then you can easily modify this in VirtualHost directive of yout httpd.conf file.

maxim

Comment: I think the same But its very difficult to start with it. any help how to use this ?? is it a software ?

Comment: Its your webserver. Your PHP runs on a webserver. So mod_rewrite is a dicrective, a command, to the webserver. If you do it this way, your pages will be showing in browser a page different from what it uses internally. Other ways with includes and variables are workarounds, but they are tricky, very easy to screw things up. You might eventually spend more time doing it modifying code in pages rather than learn apache directive mod_rewrite. Its not taht hard at the end...

Comment: For your info. I am using phpbb forum. Can you guide accordngly.please

Answer (score 0):

Use the Apache mod_rewrite module, see below :

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

http://docforge.com/wiki/Clean_URL

Comment: you are using the core php. so you need to use apache directive URLRewrite (mod_rewrite) by create a htaccess file.

Comment: I already have htaccess file created in my ftp its created for someone else. I just have to put the code .. which code and wehre I dont know..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "mask" a domain or URL. A link points to a certain URL. That URL is necessary for the browser to find the server it's supposed to send the request to and to make the request. The browser will send the request to that URL and it will display the URL it sent the request to in the address bar. You cannot make it send a request to one URL but have it display a different URL.

You can make your webserver react to that URL/request any way you want. Just because the request said "clubs.php" doesn't mean the webserver will execute a file called "clubs.php" or that it has to execute some PHP file at all. That can be customized in the webserver itself, typically through URL rewriting in Apache. That's all just internal to the webserver however, it configures how your webserver reacts to an incoming request for a certain URL; it does not "mask" the URL.

If you have links pointing to "clubs.php" but you want them to point to "groups.php" instead, you'll have to change your links. No way around it.

You *could* **redirect** all requests for "clubs.php" to "groups.php". I.e., when your webserver receives a request for "clubs.php", it responds to the client by telling it to ask for "groups.php" instead. That's a *redirection*. It will still make your links point to "clubs.php" though.

Comment: If I change all the names in the alll files??? like where every club is there i will replace it with group??

Comment: Yes. If you want your URLs to be a certain way, you have to link them a certain way. This shouldn't be too difficult using the search&replace tool of a decent text editor. For the next time, even though this may be a little advanced for you: to keep your URL schemas flexible, you can/should use a router/reverse router like https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router (shameless self promotion). Make sure to read https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router#what-urls-are-and-how-to-set-up-routing and https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-Router#reverse-routing in particular.

Comment: its a phpbb mod, what I am thking all I will clubs i will replace with groups using notepad ++ and then again i will install it will work ??